Experiment design to determine effect of ads on etsy shop performance
I am looking to design an experiment to determine the impact of turning on etsy ads for my shop. I opened a shop for plant pots and have made 27 sales in the 4 months I have been open. I am considering doing an A/B test to determine the effect of the ads, but I have a couple concerns.

One of the pots is by the best seller with 7 of the 27 sales. There are other pots that have 2-3 sales and then a large number with 0 sales. Mainly, how do I deal with this outlying pot potentially influencing the results? Should I take into account sales prior to ads in the inference model? Do I leave this pot out of the analysis?
I am worried about spillover from the products with ads to the products without ads. Namely: if people see the ads, click on the shop, and then end up purchasing a different product from the shop. Does this mean I could only potentially answer the question of "how does having ads on half my products impact sales for my whole shop" by comparing pre-ad sales to post-ad sales? Instead of "how do ads affect the sales of specific products compared to if they did not have ads" by comparing treated (ads) vs non-treated (no ads)?

Thank you very much for the help. Any advice, literature, or learning material would be greatly appreciated. I am currently working my way through Causal Inference in Python by Matheus Facure.

How did you pick which pots get ads?

hey @dimitriy, I have not picked which pots get ads yet. I was initially thinking of simple randomization at a 50/50 split but then got worried about my outlying best seller pot skewing the results.

I think a simple pre-post analysis is going to be challenging. Since sales are infrequent, you would need two long periods to detect any difference. But that means you will conflate the effect of ads with seasonal factors and changes in reputation, review, and ranking. For example, suppose ads make a product sell very well (compared to a world with no ads). In that case, customers will buy and leave some reviews that can alter the experience of customers who arrive later during the no-ad period but see traces of that induced activity that tip them into buying.
You might be tempted to "pulse" the advertising, switching products on and off at random every day. But that only works if ads on one day do not affect demand the following no-ad day, which seems unlikely. It's probably a pain to set up all these ad campaigns.
But you still may be able to implement a crossover design: 
Here, you split the pots into two groups: A and B. Group A is treated with ads, and Group B is control for the first half of the experiment. In the second half, Group B is treated and Group A is control. To minimize the bias from the carry-over effect of marketing (or long attribution windows), you would implement a blackout period at the beginning of the first and second half of the experiment. Weeks 7 and 10 are blacked out because they are dropped from the analysis, but have the same treatment status as weeks 8 and 11, respectively. The data would be a product-day-level. You could even repeat this over time, shuffling the composition of the two groups to avoid the outlier effect of that one very popular pot. It might also make sense to have a cooldown period with all marketing off when you swap the groups. I would also exclude this interval from the analysis.
But that still leaves the shop spillover effect you are rightly concerned with. You may be able to handle that by gradually ramping up the size of the treatment group. Here is the intuition. If only one pot is sponsored, that probably has little effect on all the others. With more pots treated, that becomes concerning. If you see the effect really change with the size of the treatment group, that indicates spillovers that matter. If the effect of ads is stable over time, spillovers are not worth worrying about. I do have some concerns about power: you may not be able to detect the differences.
Another way to grapple with this is to try to sign the bias. I think this spillover makes ads look less effective because the control group is getting some extra traffic induced by the ad as people discover your shop. If you still find that the ads offer a decent ROI, then the bias is not big enough to get you to a wrong decision. But if the ROI looks meh, that's a different story.
A third solution is to split your shop in two and advertise in one shop only. This would effectively shut down the spillover through your shop page. No idea if this is feasible on Etsy. However, you could still have spillovers through changes in ranking if advertised pots from store 1 force the control pots from store 2 to land lower on the page or get shoved to the next page. This channel is also a concern for the crossover design above.

Thank you so much for your insight! This is all very much food for thought. I will try and implement the crossover design you suggested.
